# setOnClickListener on items within getView bad behavior

Tags: android, adapter, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

I am facing a really strange behaviour where I set an onClickListener on checkboxes and their labels, within a custom adapter.
The problem is when I check an answer on the first question, the same item on the 3rd question is checked too. The checkboxes seems to be synchronised, but i don't understand why.

Here is some screens to understand.

[1rst question](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/45/1415283904-screenshot-2014-11-06-15-23-00.png)

[3rd question](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/45/1415283875-screenshot-2014-11-06-15-23-04.png)

Here is the getView() from my adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi = convertView;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_item, null);
    }

    Qcm qcm = qcms.get(position);
    List<Proposition> propositions = qcm.getPropositionsList();

    TextView numQuestion = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_number_item);
    TextView question = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
    LinearLayout[] labels = new LinearLayout[5];
    labels[0] = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_label1);
    labels[1] = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_label2);
    labels[2] = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_label3);
    labels[3] = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_label4);
    labels[4] = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_label5);

    final CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[5];
    checkBoxes[0] = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_check1);
    checkBoxes[1] = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_check2);
    checkBoxes[2] = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_check3);
    checkBoxes[3] = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_check4);
    checkBoxes[4] = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.question_check5);

    numQuestion.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
    question.setText(Html.fromHtml(qcm.getQuestion()));

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        final int cpt = i;


        checkBoxes[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Checked[i] -> !Checked[i]
                QcmListAdapter.this.checked[position][cpt] = !QcmListAdapter.this.checked[position][cpt];
                APIHelper.log('d', "position="+position);
                // TODO : Faire la methode PlaySerieFragment.saveSession();
                //QcmListAdapter.this.activity.getFragmentManager().getFragment(QcmListAdapter.this.);
            }
        });


        labels[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkBoxes[cpt].performClick();
                APIHelper.log('d', "onClick:cpt="+cpt);
            }
        });

        Proposition p = propositions.get(i);
        p.setFormattedView(this.activity, labels[i], (i + 1));

    }

    return vi;

}
```

and here is the view for an item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/question_block"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/question" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_number_item"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="X"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/question_number" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Question 1 : Texte descriptif de la question tellement long"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/MPQ_blue"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/question_number_item"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/question_item1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/question" android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/question_check1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="start" android:button="@drawable/play_qcm_checkbox" android:text="" android:paddingTop="13dp"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/question_label1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/question_check1"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/question_item2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/question_item1" android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/question_check2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="start" android:button="@drawable/play_qcm_checkbox" android:text="" android:paddingTop="13dp"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/question_label2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/question_check2"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/question_item3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/question_item2" android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/question_check3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="start" android:button="@drawable/play_qcm_checkbox" android:text="" android:paddingTop="13dp"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/question_label3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/question_check3"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/question_item4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/question_item3" android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/question_check4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="start" android:button="@drawable/play_qcm_checkbox" android:text="" android:paddingTop="13dp"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/question_label4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/question_check4"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/question_item5" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/question_item4" android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/question_check5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="start" android:button="@drawable/play_qcm_checkbox" android:text="" android:paddingTop="13dp"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/question_label5" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/question_check5"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because the view is getting re-used. Android re-uses views in a listview for performance, as the view is re-used when you click the same view displays the checked state.

You can either remove the if statement around convertView

if(convertView == null)
..

But this will be determental to performance if you have a lot of items.

Otherwise you should use the common viewHolder method:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting fact, I didn't thought it was reused this way.
Is there any way to force recreating views for any occurence in getView() ?

I mean, remove the if statement just gave me a crash because convertView is null.

Comment: Sorry, my fault for a bad explanation. Remove the if, but not its contents.
So you just want this line:
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_item, null);

Comment: This is what I thinked first but, this is recreating view each time I scroll, like, state of checkboxes on each view created is not persistent.

Comment: I mean, each list item should have his own persistence because I need to keep checkbox states for each of them.

Comment: AS well as setting the onclicklistener, set its checked state based on qcm

Comment: Oh yeah I just realised... Im getting tired I think... Thank you alot for your explanations :)